# Gravity and centre of mass

Tags: gravity

Does gravity act entirely as if on the centre of mass? Often I have heard this, but it seems more realistic (even if less practical) if it acts on individual bits of matter, therefore weaker further away, shifting the "centre of gravitational attraction" closer to the attracting object than the centre of mass. Is this what the centre of gravity is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: gravity acts on individual bits of mass, and is stronger towards the source of the gravitational field. The center of mass and center of gravity correspond if you assume constant gravitational field (and rigid bodies I would say).

Comment: This is inaccurate: there's no single "source" of the gravitational field.  In a simple 2-body situation, both bodies are pulled towards the common center of mass. The field strength at any location depends on the total distribution of mass about that location (which is why, e.g. at the center of the earth the net gravitational force is zero)

Comment: You are right, there is no single source of gravitational field. 
To be clear
I made the assumption that there is a gravity field generated by a massive object (i.e. earth) and a way less massive object that does not noticeably modify the gravitational field.

Comment: you can take a look here: minute 30
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRZgW1YjCKk